# Using conditionals inside jade template with javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have this jade template that has some logic inside it, but i don't know what im doing wrong here, the code is:

```
 #container
   -for(var col=0; col < 2 ;col++){
         - if(col % 4 == 0){
              .movie_row
        - }
                 .movie_thumb

  - }
```

I want the results to be like:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="movie_row">
       <div class="movie_thumb"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="movie_row">
       <div class="movie_thumb"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

but its giving me this:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<div class="movie_row"></div>
<div class="movie_thumb"></div>
<div class="movie_row"></div>
<div class="movie_thumb"></div>
```

Am I  doing the conditions wrong? I looked at the docs, there's nothing which looks like nested conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure why you're using `% 4` in your code, but something like:

```
#container
     -for(var col=0; col < 2 ;col++) {
          .movie_row
              .movie_thumb
      - }
```

does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#container
      -for(var col=0; col<2; col++)
          -if(col%4 == 0)
              .movie_row
                .movie_thumb
```